# Unable to connect to EC2 server with my MacBook

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openssh

I am unable to connect to EC2 (CentOs) from my MacBook. When I connect it from ubuntu machine, it will be connected. Currently, I got the following the following error:

```
ec2 ssh sign_and_send_pubkey: no mutual signature supported Account locked due to 290 failed logins
```

How can I solve the problem?

I have tried the following command:

```
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@ip
```

Comment: This isn’t related to EC2 or AWS in general. It is definitely related to macOS and openSSH. You should post this question to relevant area.

Comment: You can check https://cmsgraham.wordpress.com/2018/11/14/macos-mojave-iterm2-3-2-5-ssh-error-after-upgrade-sign_and_send_pubkey-no-mutual-signature-supported/

Answer (score 32):

I was locked out and couldn't access the machine to enter in the suggested answer's change to ssh config.

I added the following argument to the `ssh` call `-o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa` and it worked.

Example:

```
ssh -i "keypair.cer" -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa ec2-user@ip
```

Note: the `ssh` call will accept both `.cer` and `.pem` filetypes.

Comment: this worked for me, but what I don't understand is what changed in either my server or my client, I haven't used these parameters before. And btw I can't connect through the web browser feature anymore as well.

Comment: @Fabio same thing happened to me! Took me forever to find this. I think Amazon changed how EC2 works.

Comment: Could be, but I'd like to clarify that I'm sure these changes did NOT happen on my live instance since I had no automatic or manual updates since I last logged in. I also re-started an instance I had down since 2016~ish and faced same problem.

Answer (score 17):

edit or create the file `~/.ssh/config` and add the following content:

```
Host *
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss
```

After that, try again.